# in a procedure what is the difference between one begin end or many begin end？

Tags: oracle, plsql

WE ALWAYS see this structure in a PLSQL procedure,but if i use many begin end, what  is the difference? Some people like to write a lot of BEGIN, END nested,And some  procedures only write a pair of BEGIN, why?This creates another problem ,Does EXCEPTION have to end before END,
If you want to define multiple EXCETPION in a procedure, you must define multiple BEGIN, END.

```
BEGIN
...
EXCEPTION WHEN .. THEN
...
END
```

---

```
BEGIN

begin
...
end;

begin
...
end;

...
EXCEPTION WHEN .. THEN
...
END
```

I want to know is there any benefit to write the code in many begin end?
I would appreciate it if you could explain it to me,thank u

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what procedure does; sometimes it is simple `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END`, sometimes it is more of them (enclosed into "master" `BEGIN-END`).

Example of multiple blocks:

```
declare
  l_salary number;
begin
  -- I "hope" there's just one CLERK. If there's none or more of them, I want to handle it
  begin
    select salary into l_salary
    from emp
    where job = 'CLERK';
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      l_salary := 150;
    when too_many_rows then
      l_salary := 100;
  end;
  dbms_output.put_line('CLERK: ' || l_salary);

  -- I "hope" there's just one SALESMAN. If there's none or more of them, I want to handle it
  begin
    select salary into l_salary
    from emp
    where job = 'SALESMAN';
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      l_salary := 250;
    when too_many_rows then
      l_salary := 200;
  end;
  dbms_output.put_line('SALESMAN: ' || l_salary);
end;
```

---

If it were just one BEGIN-END, I wouldn't be able to handle two `SELECT`s that failed because I don't know *which one* failed:

```
declare
  l_salary number;
begin
  select salary into l_salary f
  from emp 
  where job = 'CLERK';
  dbms_output.put_line('CLERK': ' || l_salary');

  select salary into l_salary f
  from emp 
  where job = 'SALESMAN';
  dbms_output.put_line('SALESMAN': ' || l_salary');

exception
  when no_data_found then
    l_salary := ???;         --> what to put here? Did CLERK's or SALESMAN's
  when too_many_rows then
    l_salary := ???;         --> what to put here?
end;
```

---

Another usage of nested `BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END` is within a loop; if code (in loop) fails, then loop stops. If you handle error, you let other loop rounds to continue. This is particularly useful when you have set-oriented query which fails, and you have no idea what/who is the culprit. In a loop, you can *isolate* it (a-ha! OK, now I know what to fix!) and then re-run the original query.
For example:

```
declare
  l_salary number;
begin
  for cur_r in (select distinct job from emp) loop
    begin
      select salary into l_salary
      from emp
      where job = cur_r.job;
    exception
      when others then
        dbms_output.put_Line(cur_r.job ||': '|| sqlerrm);
    end;   
  end loop;
end;
```

Without it:

```
declare
  l_salary number;
begin
  for cur_r in (select distinct job from emp) loop
      select salary into l_salary
      from emp
      where job = cur_r.job;
  end loop;

exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('SELECT failed, but I do not know for which job and ' ||
                         ' I can not reference cur_r.job outside of the loop);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The full syntax is

```
declare
    ...
begin
    ...
exception
    ...
end;
```

`declare` and `exception` are optional.

On their own these keywords do nothing, so

```
begin
    do_stuff(1);

    begin
        do_stuff(2);
    end;

    do_stuff(3);
end;
```

is the same thing as

```
begin
    do_stuff(1);
    do_stuff(2);
    do_stuff(3);
end;
```

Sub-blocks like these are only useful if you want to either `declare` something for one specific section only, for example

```
begin
    do_stuff(1);

    declare
        some_variable_only_valid_here integer;
    begin
        do_stuff(some_variable_only_valid_here);
    end;

    do_stuff(3);
end;
```

or if you want an `exception` for some specific step (this is a great way to track error details - a beginner mistake is to write enormous rambling procedures with just one exception handler at the bottom, which then doesn't capture enough information about the error to be useful, such as exactly which step failed or what parameter values it couldn't handle).

```
begin
    do_stuff(1);

    begin
        how_about_we_give_this_a_try(2);
    exception
        when zero_divide then
            raise_application_error(-20123, 'Really specific details help', true);
    end;

    do_stuff(3);
end;
```

or of course both.

If a sub-block becomes complex, with many local variables and lines of code etc, then you might consider refactoring it as a separate procedure, for example:

```
begin
    do_stuff(1);

    launch_rocket_into_space(2);

    do_stuff(3);
end;
```

where `launch_rocket_into_space()` is a procedure that calls `how_about_we_give_this_a_try()` and handles zero divide errors.